# Create new screen or retrieve existing screen?

Tags: flutter

When I am working on flutter navigator, I could not figure out what is the right way to create a screen.

For example, I have a Home screen and a Products screen. When app load, Home created, and then click a button there to go to Products screen, from Products I can go back to Home.

In this case, two screens are in the navigator stack. If I go to a third screen, and click the Products menu on the drawer list, it will create a new Products screen. Now there are two products screen in the stack.
My question is:

1. It seems it is normal to have multi instance of same screen in the stack, right?
2. Is it a good idea to always keep only one instance of one screen in the stack, and is it possible?
3. If we have to have multi instance of same screen in stack, isn't it wise to only load initial data once? for example, in this case, is it a good practice to keep the products list somewhere and don't pull data from server every time a new Products screen created?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1, It seems it is normal to have multi instance of same screen in the stack, right?

No, it's not normal to have multi instance of same screen.

> 2, Is it a good idea to always keep only one instance of one screen in the stack, and is it possible?

Yes and it's possible with push and pop. Push is adding a new instance on the stack, pop will remove the top stack. It is a good practice to use pop when returning to previous page.

> 3, If we have to have multi instance of same screen in stack, isn't it wise to only load initial data once?

Depends on the data. If it is mutable throughout, then it is not wise to only load it once. If it is persistent throughout the app's lifetime, use Shared preferences plugin to store it. If it is a constant, storing it in a local database would be better.